# Explanation of a step in proof of Triangle Inequality for Contour Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to follow this proof on proof wiki https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality_for_Contour_Integrals

as I think the proof relates to a problem I am working on, however I do not understand the step

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i \mathop = 1}^n \int_{a_i}^{b_i} \left\vert{ f \left({\gamma_i \left({t}\right) }\right) }\right\vert \left\vert{ \gamma_i' \left({t}\right) }\right\vert  \ \mathrm dt \leq \displaystyle \sum_{i \mathop = 1}^n \max_{t \mathop \in \left[{a_i\,.\,.\,b_i}\right] } \left\vert{ f \left({\gamma_i \left({t}\right) }\right) }\right\vert \int_{a_i}^{b_i} \left\vert{ \gamma_i' \left({t}\right) }\right\vert  \ \mathrm dt$$

The reason given on proofwiki is Linear Combination of Integrals but I do not understand how that applies here.

Comment: $$\int_a^b |f| |g| \, dt \le \int_a^b (\max |f|) |g| \, dt = (\max |f|) \int_a^b |g| \, dt.$$

Comment: Why? What can I search to find that result?

Comment: This is a basic result about integrals: if you have two functions $f$ and $g$ for which $0 \le f \le g$, then $\int_a^b f \le \int_a^b g$. You can find the proof in any real analysis textbook.

Comment: Okay, I get it now, thank you